# jupyter notebook keeps dying while training

Tags: deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-kernel

When executing model-training code on jupyter notebook(with cu11.7), the kernel fails to proceed more than 1 epoch and the kernel continues to die as below.

What's strange is that when running the same code in a pycharn venv, the training proceeds without any problems.

Please give me some advice. Thank you.

[image: 1]

I also modified the max_buffer_size and reinstalled the jupyter-notebook, but it did not work. I checked through the window task manager that it is not a problem with cpu or memory.

And I also uninstalled and reinstalled ipykernel, ipython, jupyter_client, jupyter_core, traitlets, ipython_genutils. But it didn't work